# Can't Import SQL Database to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a website that uses phpmyadmin and MySQL for the database

I am currently working on a localhost copy of my website.

The web server is running the following for the website database:
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 5.5.62-log - Source distribution
Protocol version: 10
User: sql_indianrivern@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)

The local host is running the following for its database:
Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.4.22-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)

I use the Quick Export function on the web server through phpMyAdmin to export my database.

When I go to import the database to the local host phpmyadmin, I get the following error:

```
Error
Static analysis:

11 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected character. (near "{" at position 345)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "doctype" at position 2)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "html" at position 10)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "html" at position 17)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "lang" at position 22)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near ""en"" at position 27)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "dir" at position 32)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near ""ltr"" at position 36)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "head" at position 44)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "meta" at position 53)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "charset" at position 58)
SQL query: Copy

<!doctype html> <html lang="en" dir="ltr"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"> <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer"> <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"> <style id="cfs-style">html{display: none;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  ...' at line 1
```

That can be possibly causing the error I am getting? How do I fix this so I can import my database to my localhost server.

I have attempted to look at the different export settings to export the database differently. However, I am not very familiar the various settings and I have no idea if they would do anything to fix my issue.

Edit: Here is the link to my exported .sql database: https://indianrivernews.us/advertisements.sql

Comment: Looks like we'll need to see your export file

Comment: Here is the link to download the SQL Database: https://indianrivernews.us/advertisements.sql

Comment: Your file is HTML, it's not SQL. See what you can import into phpMyAdmin - https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/import_export.html